# Ajax not sending data at all

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

im working on a script that sends a few data stored using GET to a PHP script(process it then put it into database).

here's the ajax script , im using jQuery ajax
(i have included the latest jQuery script)

```
function send(){
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://examplewebsite.com/vars/parse.php",
     data: "id=" + id + "&purl=" + purl + "&send" + "true",
     cache: false,
     success: function(){
       alert("Sent");

     }
  });
}
```

`id` and `purl` are JavaScript variables .

`send()` function is set in :

```
<a href="#" onclick="send()">Send</a>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

//Connect to database
include ("config.php");

//Get the values
$id = $_GET['id'];
$purl = $_GET['purl'];
$send = $_GET['send'];

if ($send == 'true') {


    $insertdata = "INSERT INTO data (id,purl,send) VALUES ('$id','$purl',+1)";
    mysql_query($insertdata) or die(mysql_error());
} else {
    //do nothing
}
?>
```

when i type ***http://examplewebsite.com/vars/parse.php?id=123&purl=example&send=true***
it works, the php injects the data into the database as i wanted but when i use `send()` and wanted to use ajax to send the data, failed.

Is there any mistakes that im making?

Comment: Is your page on the examplewebsite.com domain? Domain name and port must match exactly for a normal Ajax call to work

Comment: use inspector to investigate the request and params sent by browser. also, I would suggest using array() in data field instead of string.

Comment: What are possible values of `id` and `purl`? Maybe the problem is that you are not encoding these values. Try `data: {id: id, purl:purl, send: true},` instead.

Comment: yes its an actual and valid domain name.

Comment: @Felix , id value should be something like ab23mn68 (combination of words and numbers) , while purl is a short URL.

Comment: It can be a valid domain, but it has to be the same domain of the page the script is executed on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: oh i see. i will try out JSON

Comment: BTW GET requests are supposed to be idempotent, i.e. they should not change anything on the server. If you insert data into a database, you should use POST.

Comment: It's always a good idea if your ajax is not working then check the params by putting alert...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the = after send,

```
function send(){

  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://examplewebsite.com/vars/parse.php",
     data: "id=" + id + "&purl=" + purl + "&send=" + "true",
     cache: false,
     success: function(){
       alert("Sent");

     }
  });
}
```

should fix it, also. post more information about your javascript. We just have to assume id and purl are filled out. Did you try debugging them (if this doesn't work).

Also, debug the URL that is requested, you can use firefox or chrome dev-tools for this. What url is being send to the PHP page and is it correct

Comment: For anyone working with Ajax, the "Network" pane in the web inspector is your friend. It shows you exactly what data you're sending (or aren't sending)...

Comment: @Felix yes. but that is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

missing "=" in the data string.

```
 data: "id=" + id + "&purl=" + purl + "&send" + "true",
```

should be

```
 data: "id=" + id + "&purl=" + purl + "&send=" + "true",
```

Comment: Good catch with the `=`. You still should encode the values though.

Comment: Felix , what do you mean by encoding? sorry im still a newbie.

Comment: yep. better to use array/object as value for data param

Comment: @edward: [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Percent-encoding). You are sending a URL as value of one of the parameters. You have to encode that value so that the characters are not interpreted as belonging to the "main URL".

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you are running your script, because ajax calls are not meant to work on other domains. If you need to run the js on http://example1.com and the call to go to http://example2.com you need another approach.

An idea is to use [json](http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/web-development/javascript/jsonp-example/)

Comment: How does JSON help to make cross-domain calls?

Comment: that means Ajax is not suitable to be used on other domain? my site is (for example) , www.abc.com , while the script is on www.bbb.com. it cant work?

Comment: @brianreavis: JSONP is not JSON (but actually I thought that the OP makes a POST request, so yes, JSONP will work here (although he really should use a POST request)).

Comment: JSONP is just JSON wrapped in a callback... no need to split hairs.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data: { id: id, purl: purl, send: true }
```

See if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

First, i suggest (if you use Chrome or Safari) to use the *Web Inspector* (Right Click anywhere - inspect element) and then press ESC to show to console, this will assist you in validating your JS code. That would show you you have a  '=' missing.

Second, i would try something a bit more simple just to make sure you get to the file.

JS:

```js
// Don't forget encoding the data before sending, this is just a simple example
$.get("parse.php?sent=true",
     function(data){
         alert("I think i got a nibble...");
         alert(data);
     }
);
```

On the php file :

```php
$sent = (isset($_GET['sent']) && !empty($_GET['sent']))?$sent:false;

if($sent) echo 'whatever data you want back';
```

Just make sure that you actually get the alert, and if so , move on from there to build the PHP file as needed for your data.

Hope this assists,
Shai.